# SCSS - Need to remove line number comments in output CSS file

Tags: html, css, sass

I have used SCSS in my project (Mac).

Issue: i need to remove Line Number Comments (/* line Number */) in output CSS.

Any Solution?

Comment: some sort of minifier would seem to be in order.

Comment: Use SCSS comments instead 
`// line Number`

Comment: i tried "sourceComments": false in .bracket.json. but it's not working

Answer (score 1):

See the [documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#Options):

> #line_numbers-option :line_numbers : When set to true, causes the line number and file where a selector is defined to be emitted into the compiled CSS as a comment. Useful for debugging, especially when using imports and mixins. This option may also be called :line_comments. Automatically disabled when using the :compressed output style or the :debug_info/:trace_selectors options.

Set that option to off or use the compressed output style.